# Why is ContentResolver.setIsSyncable not working for me?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter, android-account

I am writing an app which uses the [SyncAdapter framework](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). By default, the user has to activate the sync in the android account settings.

However, I was told that by [calling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setIsSyncable(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) 

   `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable (mAccount, AUTHORITY,1);`

I can activate the syncing without any user interaction.

Sadly, this doesn't seem to work. Even after a complete reinstall of the app, the sync adapter service is not running and the account settings look like this:(See screenshot below.)

What could I possibly be missing? Is it a problem maybe that I am calling `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable (mAccount, AUTHORITY,1);` from the content provider as opposed to the activity?

[image: Screenshot account settings]

Comment: As an aside, is there a way to make the graphic render a bit smaller?

Comment: Are you expecting to see something other than "Sync is OFF"?  Have you also called `requestSync()`. `setSyncAutomatically()`, or `addPeriodicSync()` as described in a later section of the [training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html) you referenced?

Comment: @qbix Sure I am also calling `requestSync()` :) . I am not sure what I am expecting to see in the settings, but I expect the sync to work without further user interaction.

Comment: If you followed the all the steps in the training guide, I probably can't suggest anything you don't already know.  I'm not an expert, but I did implement a SyncAdapter using the guide and it is being invoked.  Maybe double check the declaration of the adapter in your manifest and adapter meta-data.  If you want to post them, I'd look at them and compare with mine.

Comment: @qbix Thanks for your help. The point is that the sync adapter is running after I check the little check box. So I guess my configuration is mostly fine. The issue I have is that the checkbox needs to be checked. I thought `setIsSyncable` would resolve this,  but it doesn't. Hence my question.